# How to replace text contained in one row with text contained in another row using a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am crafting a sql query that dynamically builds a where clause. I was able to transform the separate pieces of the where clause as return rows like so:

```
-------------------------------------------
| ID      | Query Part                    |
-------------------------------------------
| TOKEN 1 | (A = 1 OR B = 2)              |
-------------------------------------------
| TOKEN 2 | ([TOKEN 1] or C = 3           |
-------------------------------------------
| TOKEN 3 | ([TOKEN 2] and D = 4)         |
-------------------------------------------
```

My goal is to wrap the current return results above in a stuff and or replace (or something entirely different I hadn't considered) to output the following result:

(((A=1 OR B=2) OR C=3) AND D=4)

Ideally there would be no temp table necessary but I am open to recommendations.

Thank you for any guidance, this has had me pretty stumped at work.

Comment: how do you apply this to a practical situation?

Comment: We have an application in production and another third party application consuming our data. We don’t want to update code to handle this so we’re trying to make this a sql function so we can integrate with this third party app

Comment: What if the row `TOKEN 4 | ([TOKEN 2] or D = 1) ` is added?  What result is expected? We need more info on your business rules regarding the data set in question.

Comment: The way the code is designed that would never occur. What could happen is Token N | ([TOKEN N-1] or Z=3). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its unusual. It looks like the query part you want is only Token 3. Then the process should replace any [token] tags in this query part with the corresponding query parts. With the subsequent resulting query part, again the process should replace any [token] tags with the corresponding query parts. This continues until there are no more [token] tags to replace.

I think there should there be a way of indicating the master query  (ie token 3) , then use a recursive common table expression to build the expression up until there are no more [token]s.

Comment: This is 100% correct. I will give this a shot. Thanks,